# TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Array)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to execute following line in rails console (bundle exec rails c):

```
query = select("product.id").where("admin_id = ? and account_id = ?", 3, 4)
```

But I get following error:

```
TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Array)
from (irb):83:in `select'
```

This code seems to be working fine in the application as such. Any clue on why it is failing in irb?

ruby version -> 1.9.3p545
Rails version -> 3.2.8

This code is originally defined in a ActiveRecord class (Product) in a scope.
How to execute it through rails console ?

Comment: `irb` or `rails console`. Also what context are you executing it in. It seems you want to call it in a context of some ActiveRecord class, you are missing a receiver here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified the receiver for `select`, hence it tries to execute `select` method defined on `Kernel` module. In your application this call is wrapped within some class, which becomes a default receiver. You need  to add this receiver to your call in irb, most likely:

```
query = Product.select("product.id").where("admin_id = ? and account_id = ?", 3, 4)
```

Update:

Since this is defined as a scope, you can just use scope name to execute it:

```
query = Product.scope_name
```